# getting user logged in c# on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have a headache with a webpage.

I have only a webpage index.aspx which i am trying to get the active username logged in windows, and show all the information related to the employee.

I can´t get the username.

( i am working on iis 7.0 and all the autentification in iis are disabled)
( if i enable the **windows autentification** a prompt appears)

Here is my code:

```
  username = (String) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
   if (username == null) {
      username=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
  username =  Environment.UserName;

     PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            var user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            username = user.SamAccountName;


        }
```

as you see i have several ways to get the user logged,
but all of them appears null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved myself !!!

I needed to put this code in webconfig.

```
     <authorization>
      <allow users ="*" />
    <!--     <deny users ="*" /> -->
     </authorization>
```